# Multiply by transposing rows by date

Tags: r, date, dataframe, reshape

I want to convert this table :

```
  Person  startDate    endDate
 Person1 2018-12-31 2019-03-30
 Person2 2018-12-31 2019-01-30
 Person3 2019-02-01 2019-05-30

df1 <- data.frame(Person = paste0("Person", 1:3),
                  startDate = as.Date(c("31 12 2018", "31 12 2018", "01 02 2019"), format = "%d %m %Y"),
                  endDate = as.Date(c("30 03 2019", "30 01 2019", "30 05 2019"), format = "%d %m %Y"),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

to that table with **R**

[image]

In brief : converting the time periods between start date and end date to months table vertically

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far? How are you getting from the first version to the second?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(lubridate)
df1 %>%
    transmute(Person, Date = map2(dmy(StartDate), dmy(EndDate), ~
                           seq(.x, .y, by = '1 month') %>%
                                 format('%b %Y'))) %>%
    unnest(Date)
```

Comment: And a `data.table` way: `library(data.table); setDT(df1); df1[, .(Date = format(seq.Date(from = startDate, to = endDate, by = "month"), "%b %Y")), by=Person]`